# unable to download android SDK versions and extra's(add ons)

Tags: android, installation

I have downloaded new android setup bundle file with the name "adt-bundle-windows-x86" from the official android developers site ([enter link description here](http://developer.android.com/sdk/index.html)) and followed the instructions specified in "Setting Up the ADT Bundle" option of the same site(http://developer.android.com/sdk/installing/bundle.html) to set up the development environment. i opened the eclipse as per the instructions from that site and checked for the platforms available and found only Android4.2(API 17) only. so i've decided to install and google maps api addon and previous versions. i.e 2.2 and above all versions.

But if i open eclipse -> Window -> Android SDK Manager i am unable to see the options to install any of the platforms and addons. showing the below screen shot only.[image]

please help me to solve this issue.

Answer (score 0):

One thing you could do is, go into he Android SDK manager:

Select into Tools/Options . Uncheck download cache and click in cleaar cache
Then Packages/reload